# when would you use uint_least16_t

Tags: c

I'm looking at stdint.h and given that it has uint16_t and uint_fast16_t, what is the use for uint_least16_t what might you want that couldn't be done equally well with one of the other two?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Say you're working on a compiler with:

- `unsigned char` is 8 bits
- `unsigned short` is 32 bits
- `unsigned int` is 64 bits

And unsigned int is the 'fastest'.  On that platform:

- `uint16_t` would *not* be available
- `uint_least16_t` would be a 32 bit value
- `uint_fast16_t` would be a 64 bit value

A bit arcane, but that's what it's for.

How useful they are is another story - I see the exact size variants all the time.  That's what people want.  The 'least' and 'fast' versions I've seen used pretty close to never (it's possible that it was only in example code - I'm really not sure).

Comment: From this answer can it be inferred that coders who aim to write *maximally* portable code should **never use uint16_t** and should always use uint_least16_t or uint_fast16_t?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the link Patrick posted includes this "The typedef name uint_leastN_t designates an unsigned integer type with a width of at least N, such that no unsigned integer type with lesser size has at least the specified width."

So my current understanding is:

uint_least16_t the smallest thing that is capable of holding a uint16

uint_fast16_t the fastest thing that is capable of holding a uint16

uint16_t exactly a uint16, unfortunately may not be available on all platforms, on any platform where is is available uint_least16_t will refer to it. So if it were guaranteed to exist on all platforms we wouldn't need uint_least16_t at all.

Comment: Yes - but uint16_t is not guaranteed to exist; think Cray (64-bit integers were all they had - int and long).

Comment: yeah... that'd be the bit where I said "unfortunately may not be available on all platforms"

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the c standard. It doesn't need a good use case. :P

See [this](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) page and look for the section titled "Minimum-width integer types".

Comment: It has a good use case: E.g. a for-loop counting from 0 to 32000; what type shall the counter variable be? 16 bit? But that might be awfully slow on a 32 bit platform with no native 16 bit type. 32 bit? But that will be awfully slow on a 16 or 8 bit platform. Since the exact bit width won't matter as long as there are at least 16 bit, uint_fast16_t is the ideal type here. However, when you store an array with 1 Mio such values, uint_least16_t might be better, since it might be much smaller than uint_fast16_t (saving you megabytes of memory).