# When is it a good idea to use uint_least16_t as opposed to uint16_t?

Tags: c, c99

I see the utility of the 'fast' integers (like `uint_fast16_t`) but I simply can't imagine a good reason to use `uint_least16_t` in lieu of `uint16_t`.

Can someone please enlighten me on the use of 'least' integers?

P.S. - This question is not a duplicate of [when would you use uint_least16_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249468/when-would-you-use-uint-least16-t) because this doesn't ask for the purpose of `uint_least16_t` in isolation; it asks for the purpose of `uint_least16_t` when the system also supports `uint16_t`.

The accepted answer in the similar question implies that `uint_least16_t` is to be used defensively because not all platforms may support `uint16_t` - **that is not an acceptable answer for this question**.

Comment: @一二三 Added a P.S. to the question to explain why it is not a duplicate of the aforementioned question.'

Comment: AFAIK your quote "uint_least16_t is to be used defensively because not all platforms may support uint16_t" IS the reason why the "least" types exist. If that is not an acceptable answer, I have no idea what you're asking -> voting to close as unclear. Cheers.

Comment: It's not clear what else you are expecting from any further answer - the accepted answer on the linked duplicate seems pretty comprehensive to me ? What problem are you trying to solve ?

Comment: @PaulR - Not comprehensive at all. The other accepted answer pretty much implies that uint_least16_t is useful only on platforms which don't support uint16_t. My question is, is there **any** good reason to use uint_least16_t on platforms which do support uint16_t?

Comment: It depends on how much you care about portability - if you know that all the platforms you are ever likely to target have support for `uint16_t`, then you will probably never need to consider using `uint_least16_t`. OTOH if you're writing, say, a library, that might be used on DSPs or other more esoteric CPUs then you might need to code more defensively and consider the possibility that `uint16_t` might not be supported.